# Python Ta-lib correct order

Tags: python, ta-lib

I refer to [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/)

In which order do I have to pass Data inside TA-Lib? The most recent data first or the most recent data last? I can't find any information, in most cases the order is not important but in some it is.

For example the momentum indicator

```
real = MOM(Stockprice, timeperiod=10)
```

| Date | Stockprice |
| --- | --- |
| 12/12/20 8:00 | 30,00 |
| 12/12/20 9:00 | 31,00 |
| 12/12/20 10:00 ​ | 32,00 |

| Date | Stockprice |
| --- | --- |
| 12/12/20 10:00 | 32,00 |
| 12/12/20 9:00 | 31,00 |
| 12/12/20 8:00 ​ | 30,00 |